# Is the sentence, "I wrote him," grammatically correct?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

I am wondering if the sentence `I wrote him.` is grammatically correct. Can `I wrote him.` take the place of `I wrote him a letter.` and/or `I wrote to him.`? Can one omit the preposition `to`? Can one omit the (what I think is) the direct object `a letter`?

Answer (score 3):

Often even big dictionaries forget to clarify problems of verb construction. "to write" is a good example. I checked  Longman DCE, book form, and Oxford COD, book form. Neither dictionary covers the problem.
Nor do Collins and Macmillian, online.

Only OALD has clear information as to verb construction. In "to write" no. 3, OALD has

1 to write to someone

2 to write someone something

3 to write something (to someone)

and

4 to write someone - AmE

http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/write?q=write

Comment: If I understand correctly, my sentence makes sense and is grammatically correct. Thank you very much.